# Git hook: once a branch is merged into master - update JIRA status

Tags: git, github, jira, githooks, webhooks

I am new to writing git hooks. 
Here's what I'd like to do:

Once a branch XYZ is merged into master (on remote); write a hook that changes the status of a JIRA ticket associated with branch XYZ from "pending approval" to "prod ready".

My research into this so far:

1. I've figured JIRA Rest API can allow me to do this (using `POST`
   transaction + `OAuth API`).
2. Git hooks can be written in many languages
       (and I figured python would be the easiest for me as I am well
       versed in it) .
3. I should be implementing either `post-merge` or
           `post-receive` git hook to do this. The hook would essentially get the
           Branch name (my branch name is enforced to be the same as Jira name)
           ; and then do a POST using JIRA API to change the status as
           mentioned above.
4. There is such a thing as "web hooks" that are also
               an option for folks using github. My repo at the moment is github
               deployed into the organization..but we might be moving toward
               bitbucket; in which case I am concerned that webhooks will no longer be useful...

My questions:

1. Is it possible to accomplish this task?
2. If so, what githook should I
       be using? `post-merge` or `post-receive`?
3. Should I be using web hooks or
           githook?
4. Can anyone point me to an example to get me started?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use JIRA's builtin SCM integration to GitHub, and use the 'PR' event to transition your issue? You would have to enforce a PR-to-master workflow, rather than git-merge-to-master, but that's a good practice anyways...

Comment: thanks for the hint; i've put in a formal answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer ...Here's how to do it - for those interested:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/configuring-workflow-triggers-776636696.html

- Esssentially, Jira has a "workflow" section; in which you can create
  a "trigger".
- The trigger can be activated to perform a    "transition"...which is
  to say the status of the JIRA can be changed    using this trigger.
- Its all UI driven; so you don't have to script a    githook or a
  webhook